# How to pass data between various parts of the pipeline in Ktor (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Am building an API and using `intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call){}` to run some logic before each route execution. I need to pass  data from the intercept() method to the called route and
am setting data by using `call.attributes.put()` in the intercept() like this:

`val userKey= AttributeKey<User>("userK")
 call.attributes.put(userKey, userData)`

And retrieve **userData** with `call.attributes[userKey]` .
What happens is that `call.attributes[userKey]` only works in the intercept() method where I have set the attribute. It doesn't work in the route where I need it.
It throws me 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instance for key AttributeKey: userK`

I wonder if am doing things in the right way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the simplest code reproducing what you describe:

```
class KtorTest {

    data class User(val name: String)

    private val userKey = AttributeKey<User>("userK")
    private val expected = "expected name"

    private val module = fun Application.() {
        install(Routing) {
            intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
                println("intercept")
                call.attributes.put(userKey, User(expected))
            }

            get {
                println("call")
                val user = call.attributes[userKey]
                call.respond(user.name)
            }

        }
    }

    @Test fun `pass data`() {
        withTestApplication(module) {
            handleRequest {}.response.content.shouldNotBeNull() shouldBeEqualTo expected
        }
    }

}
```

I intercept the call, put the user in the attributes, and finally respond with the user in the get request. 
The test passes.

What ktor version are you using and which engine?

Comment: Am using ktor **0.9.3** with **Netty**

Comment: Then you have to show more code so we can see what you are doing. My example works, so there probably is some issue with your code.

Comment: In fact I was  defining    **val userKey = AttributeKey<User>("userK")**    twice. First in the intercept() and then in the route hoping that they will point to the same key. Thanks @andreas-volkmann

Comment: @AndreasVolkmann sir, Sorry I comment Here, I read your good article https://andreasvolkmann.github.io/posts/2018-04-27-m3u8-and-ts-segments/. I'm new to Kotlin and also encryption. I tried to find out a solution for AES-128 encryption in kotlin until the last month. But I didn't find any solution for this. my question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220798/delegate-for-android-videoview